# requests.get(url).content is blank from 8a.nu

Tags: python

I am attempting to scrape the climbing website 8a.nu with Scrapy and am having issues getting the html.

I can get the html from a different website:

```
import requests
url = 'https://datacamp.com/courses/all'
html = requests.get(url).content
html
```

out: `b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html class="no-js">\n  <head>\n  <script>\n...'`

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.8a.nu/scorecard/ranking/'
html = requests.get(url).content
html
```

out: `b''`

Here is a snippet of the source code from https://www.8a.nu/scorecard/ranking/

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="ctl00_Head1"><meta charset="utf-8" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" /><link id="ctl00_cLink" rel="canonical" href="https://www.8a.nu/scorecard/ranking/" />

    <title>8a.nu - World Ranking Outdoor Climbing</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <link href="/8aStyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/js/Common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
```

Any idea what could be causing this? I know some of the website is generated with JavaScript but I still expected to get the HTML source code with the requests module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not specific to the requests module or even python. Rather, this website is selectively deciding what to return based on the user agent of the request. You can confirm this by using curl to request the site and manually adding an appropriate user agent (that of a standard browser).

Please note that this answer is for informational purposes only. If a website is blocking by user agent, they most likely do not want their website being scraped. I would suggest you check their TOS before you proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

If the site is using JavaScript library, you have to use [ScrapyJS](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash). 
If site is not using JavaScript rendering, adding the headers might help.

I've tried changing the headers
`'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36'` and it scraped the page correctly.